# Laravel edit orders as user

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I create order system in Laravel, I can add new order as user and I can display all order as admin user. I have only problem with edit this order as user.

This is my controller

```
public function index(){
    $orders = Orders::with('category', 'type')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(6);

    return view('account.orders', compact('orders'));
}
public function store(Request $request) {

        $order = new Orders;
        $order->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $order->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
        $order->type_id = $request->input('type_id');
        $order->name = $request->input('name');
        $order->description = $request->input('description');
        $order->price = $request->input('price');
        $order->save();


    return back()->with([
        'status'=> [
            'type'=>'success',
            'content'=>'Zmiany zostały zapisane',
        ]
    ]);
}

public function edit(Orders $order_id){

    $categories = Categories::get();
    $types = OrdersCategories::get();
    $order = Orders::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->findOrFail($order_id);

    return dd($order_id);

}
```

When I click edit in user dashboard not show data from database.

Comment: please post your route here for edit order

Comment: If you are just dumping the result remove `return` before `dd` function.

Comment: Route::get('/{order}/edit', 'OrderController@edit')->name('edit');

Answer (score 0):

Try This,in your controller edit function.

```
try {
     $categories = Categories::get();
     $types = OrdersCategories::get();
     $order = Orders::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                   ->findOrFail($order_id);
     return redirect()->action('Admin\OrderController@index');    
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        return back()->withError($exception->getMessage())->withInput();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I have blade file with data from order database, but if I click edit not display this data

Comment: Share the the controller function you're displaying data from.

Comment: public function index(){
    $orders = Orders::with('category', 'type')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(6);

    return view('account.orders', compact('orders'));
}

Answer (score 0):

Because your model is called Orders. You should be using /{orders}/ instead of /{order}/ in your routes if you want to make use of route-model binding.

Change the route to `Route::get('/{orders}/edit', 'OrderController@edit')->name('edit');`

Comment: I have this route :)

Comment: no you don't. You've got: Route::get('/{order}/edit', 'OrderController@edit')->name('edit'); "order" and you should use "orders" because your model name is Orders.

Comment: I change to this  Route::get('/{orders}/edit', 'OrderController@edit')->name('edit'); and it's the same problem with display data.

Comment: If you dd() those variables in the edit function. What does it give you?